# ListView.builder builds too many items

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am trying to implement indefinite scrolling with `ListView.build`:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      final entries = [];
    
      void addData(num ind) async {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        entries.add(ind);
        print("$ind added");
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (index >= entries.length) {
                addData(index);
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              return SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

As a result I see 8 items on the screen, but the `ListView.builder` built 24 items.

Why is that? How can I change it?

I would like to get data added for visible items only.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the logic should be

```dart
home: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: entries.length + 1,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == entries.length) {
      addData(index);
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
    );
  },
),
```

Else other visible item will be filed with progress indication while itemCount is null.

Comment: no, it is not what I need. I want to add data for visible items only

Comment: do you mean show only `entries` visible data? and initially ` entries = [];` it loads item 1/s

Comment: In my case adding data is expensive. So I would like to add only for 8 visible items (to run `addData` 8 times not 24)

Comment: You can do `if (index == entries.length && index < 8) {` or better ig `entries.length < 9`

Comment: In my case I don't know the number of visible items in advance

Comment: I might not be getting it currently, but `final entries = [];` is state variable  & `index` is coming from listVeiw. Is there any gif/visual or description about rendering item & calling method you can present

Comment: My real code is more complicated. It is impossible to find a number of visible items - e.g. they could be of different size etc. The alternative purpose of my question is to determine a number of visible items.

Comment: *determine a number of visible items* I think you can check [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector)

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list
Maybe this is what you are looking for.